# Can I use internal JavaScript to cycle through elements of an SVG, adding and removing a class?

Tags: javascript, svg, interactive

I have an SVG image of a selection widget with left and right arrows and a rectangle showing a selected group of objects (see simplified code snippet below, where groups have been reduced to just a number and colored rectangle for conciseness). I want to make this SVG image interactive, so the viewer can click the arrows to cycle through the available groups, **wrapping around at the ends**. Everything needs to be within the `<svg></svg>` tags; I can't use external HTML or scripts. The SVG file will be added to an HTML webpage in an `<object>` tag to preserve interactivity.

I figured out how to make the arrows into anchor elements that light up and call a JavaScript function when clicked, but I'm not sure how to make the left and right functions change which number is visible. Currently, I have all the number/color pairs as svg groups with a common class, `cls-security`, and a unique class for the specific number, `net-0` through `net-8`. All groups with the class `cls-security` are styled with `visibility: hidden`, but the group which also has the class `on` overrides that with `visibility: visible`. My thought is that the `cycleLeft()` function should identify which element with the class `cls-security` also has the class `on`, remove the class `on` from that element, go to the previous element with the class `cls-security` **(looping around to the end if necessary)**, and add the class `on` to that element; and the `cycleRight()` function should do the same thing but move to the next element with the class `cls-security` instead of the previous element with that class. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to implement that.

Everything discussed in the above paragraph could be changed if there is a better way to go about getting the effect that I want.

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to go about doing what I want?

```html
<svg id="Object-Panel-Security" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="132" height="72" viewBox="0 0 132 72">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-txt-security {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                text-anchor: middle;
            }
            .cls-btn-security {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            a:active > .cls-btn-security {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .cls-security {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            .cls-security.on {
                visibility: visible;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-BG">
        <rect x="0" width="132" height="72"/>
        <rect x="4" y="4" width="124" height="64" fill="#dbcad1"/>
        <polygon points="27 12 27 27 31 27 31 45 27 45 27 60 25.875 60 12 36.125 12 35.875 25.875 12 27 12"/>
        <polygon points="105 12 105 27 101 27 101 45 105 45 105 60 106.125 60 120 36.125 120 35.875 106.125 12 105 12"/>
    </g>
    <text id="Object-Panel-Security-Title" class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 27)">Sec Net</text>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cycleLeft()" id="Object-Panel-Security-Cycle-Left">
        <rect x="12" y="12" width="19" height="48" fill="#bebebe" opacity="0"/>
        <polygon points="25 18 25 29 29 29 29 43 25 43 25 54 14.5 36 25 18" fill="#fff" class="cls-btn-security"/>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cycleRight()" id="Object-Panel-Security-Cycle-Right">
        <rect x="101" y="12" width="19" height="48" fill="#bebebe" opacity="0"/>
        <polygon points="107 18 107 29 103 29 103 43 107 43 107 54 117.5 36 107 18" fill="#fff" class="cls-btn-security"/>
    </a>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-X" class="cls-security net-0">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#a6a6a6"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">X</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-1" class="cls-security net-1 on">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#ca0000"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">1</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-2" class="cls-security net-2">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#7cb400"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">2</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-3" class="cls-security net-3">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#005eca"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">3</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-4" class="cls-security net-4">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#e6ba08"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">4</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-5" class="cls-security net-5">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#00a1b9"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">5</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-6" class="cls-security net-6">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#ca00b9"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">6</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-7" class="cls-security net-7">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#de7f00"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">7</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-8" class="cls-security net-8">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#00ca94"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">8</text>
    </g>
    <script>//<![CDATA[
        function cycleLeft() {
            return false;
        }
        function cycleRight() {
            return false;
        }
    //]]></script>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's probably easier to update the text element itself by ` valueText.textContent=currentValue` as well as its background color. This way your svg also becomes more compact, as you need only one label text group

Comment: @herrstrietzel The code snippet is a simplified version of my SVG for conciseness. The actual file is much larger, with multiple elements in each group instead of just a number and a rectangle, but I thought including them all was unnecessary for this question. I've added a note in the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query selectors to get the current selected one and then subtract or add a number to it.

Since you use the class "on", you can toggle the class or just add or remove them like I show in my example below.

```js
function cycleLeft() {
  const parent = document.querySelector("svg > .cls-security.on")
  const elementNum = parent.querySelector("text").innerHTML
  const num =((parseInt(elementNum) || 0) + 8) % 9
  parent.classList.remove("on")
  const newElem = document.querySelector(`svg > .cls-security.net-${num}`)
  newElem.classList.add("on")

}

function cycleRight() {
  const parent = document.querySelector("svg > .cls-security.on")
  const elementNum = parent.querySelector("text").innerHTML
  const num = ((parseInt(elementNum) || 0) + 1) % 9
  parent.classList.remove("on")
  const newElem = document.querySelector(`svg > .cls-security.net-${num}`)
  newElem.classList.add("on")
}
```

```html
<svg id="Object-Panel-Security" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="132" height="72" viewBox="0 0 132 72">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-txt-security {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                text-anchor: middle;
            }
            .cls-btn-security {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            a:active > .cls-btn-security {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .cls-security {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            .cls-security.on {
                visibility: visible;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-BG">
        <rect x="0" width="132" height="72"/>
        <rect x="4" y="4" width="124" height="64" fill="#dbcad1"/>
        <polygon points="27 12 27 27 31 27 31 45 27 45 27 60 25.875 60 12 36.125 12 35.875 25.875 12 27 12"/>
        <polygon points="105 12 105 27 101 27 101 45 105 45 105 60 106.125 60 120 36.125 120 35.875 106.125 12 105 12"/>
    </g>
    <text id="Object-Panel-Security-Title" class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 27)">Sec Net</text>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cycleLeft()" id="Object-Panel-Security-Cycle-Left">
        <rect x="12" y="12" width="19" height="48" fill="#bebebe" opacity="0"/>
        <polygon points="25 18 25 29 29 29 29 43 25 43 25 54 14.5 36 25 18" fill="#fff" class="cls-btn-security"/>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cycleRight()" id="Object-Panel-Security-Cycle-Right">
        <rect x="101" y="12" width="19" height="48" fill="#bebebe" opacity="0"/>
        <polygon points="107 18 107 29 103 29 103 43 107 43 107 54 117.5 36 107 18" fill="#fff" class="cls-btn-security"/>
    </a>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-X" class="cls-security net-0">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#a6a6a6"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">X</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-1" class="cls-security net-1 on">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#ca0000"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">1</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-2" class="cls-security net-2">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#7cb400"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">2</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-3" class="cls-security net-3">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#005eca"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">3</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-4" class="cls-security net-4">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#e6ba08"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">4</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-5" class="cls-security net-5">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#00a1b9"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">5</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-6" class="cls-security net-6">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#ca00b9"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">6</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-7" class="cls-security net-7">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#de7f00"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">7</text>
    </g>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network-8" class="cls-security net-8">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="#00ca94"/>
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)">8</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

---

Comment: This almost works how I want. The only thing missing is that it doesn't loop around from 8 to 0 when clicking right or from 0 to 8 when clicking left. My first thought for how to add that behavior is to use an `if` statement to say that IF the value is 9 THEN set it to 0, and IF the value is -1 THEN set it to 8. Is that the best way, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: @Lawton I updated my answer so you can see. You can do it with modular arithmetic, so if you do a 9 MOD 9 it returns 0 and you go back from the start, in code it would be `num % 9` when going up and to go down I do the same `% 9` but now with a `(num + 8)`, because that will subtract 1 in mod 9

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify on this way:

```html
<svg id="Object-Panel-Security" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="132" height="72" viewBox="0 0 132 72">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-txt-security {
        font-size   : 16px;
        font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-anchor : middle;
        }
      .cls-btn-security {
        opacity : 0;
        }
      a:active > .cls-btn-security {
        opacity : 1;
        }
      </style>
    </defs>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-BG">
        <rect x="0" width="132" height="72"/>
        <rect x="4" y="4" width="124" height="64" fill="#dbcad1"/>
        <polygon points="27 12 27 27 31 27 31 45 27 45 27 60 25.875 60 12 36.125 12 35.875 25.875 12 27 12"/>
        <polygon points="105 12 105 27 101 27 101 45 105 45 105 60 106.125 60 120 36.125 120 35.875 106.125 12 105 12"/>
    </g>
    <text id="Object-Panel-Security-Title" class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 27)">Sec Net</text>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cycleLeft()" id="Object-Panel-Security-Cycle-Left">
        <rect x="12" y="12" width="19" height="48" fill="#bebebe" opacity="0"/>
        <polygon points="25 18 25 29 29 29 29 43 25 43 25 54 14.5 36 25 18" fill="#fff" class="cls-btn-security"/>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cycleRight()" id="Object-Panel-Security-Cycle-Right">
        <rect x="101" y="12" width="19" height="48" fill="#bebebe" opacity="0"/>
        <polygon points="107 18 107 29 103 29 103 43 107 43 107 54 117.5 36 107 18" fill="#fff" class="cls-btn-security"/>
    </a>
    <g id="Object-Panel-Security-Network" class="cls-security">
        <rect x="35" y="34" width="62" height="22" fill="" />
        <text class="cls-txt-security" transform="translate(66 51)"></text>
    </g>
  <script>//<![CDATA[
    var colors =
      [ { ref: 'X', fill:'#a6a6a6' } 
      , { ref: '1', fill:'#ca0000' } 
      , { ref: '2', fill:'#7cb400' } 
      , { ref: '3', fill:'#005eca' } 
      , { ref: '4', fill:'#e6ba08' } 
      , { ref: '5', fill:'#00a1b9' } 
      , { ref: '6', fill:'#ca00b9' } 
      , { ref: '7', fill:'#de7f00' } 
      , { ref: '8', fill:'#00ca94' } 
      ];
    var 
      currentRef    = 1 
    , ObjPanel      = document.querySelector('#Object-Panel-Security-Network')
    , ObjPanel_Rect = document.querySelector('#Object-Panel-Security-Network > rect')
    , ObjPanel_Text = document.querySelector('#Object-Panel-Security-Network > text')
      ;
    setPanel()
      ;
    function setPanel()
      {
      ObjPanel.className = 'cls-security net-' + currentRef
      ObjPanel_Rect.setAttribute('fill', colors[ currentRef ].fill )
      ObjPanel_Text.textContent = colors[ currentRef ].ref
      }
    function cycleLeft() 
      {
      if ( currentRef > 0) currentRef--;
      setPanel();
      return false;
      }
    function cycleRight()
      {
      if ( currentRef < 8) currentRef++;
      setPanel(); 
      return false;
      }
  //]]></script>
</svg>
```

Comment: My code snippet is a simplified version of my SVG for conciseness. The actual file is much larger, with multiple elements in each group instead of just a number and a rectangle, but I thought including them all was unnecessary for the question. I've added a note in the question to reflect that. I'm afraid that means that just pulling out the color and text changes doesn't work for my end-goal.